# FreePascal CRT unit prevents output redirection

Tags: redirect, console, lazarus, freepascal, crt

I have the following issue with the FreePascal CRT unit: Once the unit is added to the project (e.g. to a simple console application which writes "Hello World" using WriteLn()), the output of the program is displayed in the Windows CMD, but cannot be redirected.

To be more detailed, the following source code

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  Classes;

begin
  WriteLn('TestOutput');
end.
```

prints "TestOutput" to the Windows Command Line and bash running in windows. The command

```
project1.exe > test.txt
```

creates a file `test.txt` with the content `TestOutput`.

Once the CRT unit is added to the project (i.e. `uses Classes, CRT;`), the string is still printed to the consoles, but **cannot** be redirected to a file or used within the console context (the file and variable will be empty).

Does anyone have a solution for this behavior?

It could be worse, but for usability it would be great to have the options of `HighVideo()` and setting the cursor's position.

Best regards

Alex

Comment: Try to explicitly specify the output target i.e. `Writeln(stdout, 'foobar');`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is not to import Crt, since the whole point of Crt is not linear textual output (cursor positioning).

Classically one could deactivate crt by using

```
assign(output,'');
rewrite(output);
```

You could try to link that code to some commandline parameter to make the output suitable for piping. But to make it look sanely it is better to then also use different (non colour, non cursorpositioning) output code.